# How do I write a VSCode extension to set a file icon for a certain file extension while leaving all other extensions as the default?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Here's my `icon-config.json`:

```json
{
    "iconDefinitions": {
        "file.myFileExt": {
            "iconPath": "./custom-icon.png"
        }
    },
    "fileExtensions": {
        "myExtension": "file.myFileExt"
    }
}
```

This works to set the file extension for `foo.myExtension` files, but any other file types (e.g. `bar.py`) have their icons removed. How can I specify a custom extension icon without overwriting all other file types to be blank?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [issue 14662](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14662).

VScode 1.64 (Jan. 2022) should include [issue 140047](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140047): "finalize icon property of the language contribution point" ([commit d335676](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/d335676bfb09d61cdd5252bf00b16f7f04762287))/

> Language contributors can define an icon for the language.
>
> ```json
> {
>  "contributes": {
>    "languages": [
>      {
>        "id": "latex",
>        // ...
>        "icon": {
>          "light": "./icons/latex-light.png",
>          "dark": "./icons/latex-dark.png"
>        }
>      }
>  ]
> ```
>
> The icon is used by file icon themes as fallback if they don't have an icon for the language.